# render different html based on even/odd in foreach (php)

Tags: php, html, foreach, split

Hello I want to render different html based on odd or even post in `foreach`. I have this code by now:

```
<?=fuel_edit('create', 'Create Post', 'blog/posts')?>
<?php if (!empty($posts)) : ?>
    <?php foreach($posts as $post) : ?>
        <div class="cell small-12 large-6"></div>
        <div class="cell small-12 large-6">
            <div class="post">
                <?=fuel_edit($post)?>

                <?=blog_block('post_unpublished', array('post' => $post))?>

                <h2><a href="<?=$post->url?>"><?=$post->title?></a></h2>

                <div class="post_date">
                    <?=day($post->publish_date, 'd')?>.<?=month($post->publish_date, 'm')?>
                    <!--by <strong><span class="post_author_name"></*?=$post->author_name?></span></strong-->
                </div>

                <div class="post_content">
                    <?php if ($post->has_thumbnail_image()) : ?>
                        <img src="<?=$post->get_thumbnail_image_path()?>" alt="">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="post_meta">
                    <?=$post->tags_linked ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php else: ?>
<div class="no_posts">
    <p>There are no posts available.</p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want when is odd to render first `<div class="cell small-12 large-6"></div>` which is empty and when is even this div to be after second `<div class="cell small-12 large-6"></div>`

Please  help me I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know if a post is even or odd in your list of posts, you can track the loop index as you loop through the posts.

In the following sample, `$index` is increased each time the loop is executed. By checking if `$index` is divisible by 2, you know that it's even and render the required content:

```
<?php $index = 0; foreach($posts as $post) : ?>
  <?php if($index % 2 == 0) { $?>
    <!-- HTML for even post here. -->
  <?php } else { ?>
    <!-- HTML for odd post here. -->
  <?php 
    } 
    $index = $index + 1;
  ?> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```